# Принудительная колизия двух статических тел в Box2D

Tags: c++, box2d

Как принудительно заставить контактировать два статических тела? по умолчанию между ними колизии нет, т.е. эта установка выше чем фильтра..
Для чего нужно?
хотел создать статический взрыв внутри статических объектов, после чего по потери жизни они становились динамическими и разлетались от статического взрыва.

Comment: Может просто применить к ним силу?

Comment: Статичные тела по определению не могут друг на друга влиять, грубо говоря, их масса стремится к бесконечности, на практике на них просто не действует физика. Так что если вы хотите отбросить их в разные стороны, то нужно сделать каждое такое тело динамическим и применить силу к каждому из них.

Comment: да это все понятно что можно раскидать тела, я хотел именно использовать сами свойства бокс2д чтобы не колхозить код )))

Comment: единственно приближенный вариант получился это- создается статическое тело, через 1 шаг оно становится динамическим, оно колизирует и от него отталкиваются тела но и он сам отталкивается... а нужно чтобы стоял на месте

Comment: Раз вы пытаетесь сделать эффект взрыва путем коллизии - то вам совсем **не** понятно, как работают коллизии и силы, действующие на тела.

Comment: )))) Да с чего же? я просто хотел не высчитывать вектора от центра взрыва  , вот и все, но видимо это не тот путь..

Comment: Почитайте, что вообще такое сила, приложенная к телу, статичные тела по определению **никак** не могут воздействовать друг на друга. У них бесконечная масса. Попробуйте в жизни два предмета друг с другом рядом положить, они от этого разве разлетятся в стороны? Взрыв - это источник силы, воздействующей на ваши объекты, **без** вычисления вектора этой силы вы никак не решите эту задачу правильно.

Comment: ок, вопрос закрыт, не получится как я хотел =)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this_object && any_object)
        {
            if ((std::string)any_object->type == (std::string)"world_body")
            {
                any_object->hitme = true;
                any_object->hitdamage = this_object->Damage;
                contact->SetEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```

решил вопрос пропуском контакта после воздействия и все..